# Running Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad 81WE via USB external SSD, how to set up dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

My new laptop is similar to this: https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_3_15IIL05?M=81WE001ACF but with only 128 GB SSD so I thought I would use the 512 GB SSD from my Thinkpad (I cracked the screen accidentally).

I connected my SSD to my new laptop using this:  https://www.amazon.ca/ORICO-External-Enclosure-Optimized-Transparent/dp/B01LY97QE8

Then I went into Bios and tried to boot from a USB device which took me to Grub Rescue with message "no such partition blah blah".

I panicked but found this:  http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu?amp=1

Followed method 1 and was able to get the Grub menu and start Ubuntu 20.04 on the external SSD.

I went into the laptop Bios and changed two settings:

Legacy or UEFI: I chose Legacy
UEFI First or Legacy First (I chose Legacy First)

Now everytime I reboot, it seems to boot from the external SSD so to use the Windows 10 on the 128GB built in SSD, I think I have to go into Bios, reset the UEFI and UEFI First.

The Windows 10 on my 512 GB SSD is wrecked so I actually deleted it and made two partitions, one NTSF and one EXT4.

How can I get GRUB to recognize both SSD's and let me choose between Ubuntu on the external SSD and Windows 10 on the built-in SSD?

Or if this is impossible, what is my best option?

Edit: not sure if this is helpful but Boot Repair url: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hFhbgNX4qd/

Comment: If both Ubuntu and Windows boot in the same Legacy/UEFI mode, all you need to do is run `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu and it will add Windows to Ubuntu;s GRUB MENU. Ubuntu's GRUB will not boot Windows if there boot modes are different.

Comment: To confirm boot modes & configuration: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  External drive should have boot loader on it, And if UEFI it needs an ESP. External drives boot from a drive entry, just like the live installer.

Comment: @oldfred will do, in the meantime, my hack is to set to Legacy, and UEFI First, press and hold F12 which takes me to the screen (not sure if it's called Bios) but before boot, lets me choose among USB device or the internal SSD so I choose the USB device and I get my GRUB menu that is on the external SSD.

Comment: if I want Windows 10, UEFI first takes me to Windows directly.

Comment: If in same boot mode then C.S. Cameron's suggestion will work. Otherwise you have to always do as you are doing & select from UEFI one time boot menu every time. If external drive was UEFI with an ESP, you can reinstall grub in UEFI mode & convert install to UEFI. If just BIOS on MBR(msdos), more difficult to convert. And you have to just manually select every time.